# Do Melons prefer to grow in certain directions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'd like to do some fancy-schmancy redstone shenanigans exploiting the fact that melon blocks growing into a square can hold a charge (and thus complete a circuit). Is the direction they spawn the melon truly random?

I did a small-scale test, and got 3/4 melons spawning in the same direction. I don't want to pronounce Melons to be non-random though, as it's still a very small sample size.

[image]

Comment: I'm curious, are you trying to utilize the (possible) randomness or to eliminate it?

Comment: @Fambida Utilize it. I want to make Schrödinger's Cow. Obviously, if I can't get two equally random possibilities, the cow can't be simultaneously dead and alive.

Comment: @ Raven That's assuming that dead or alive is two separate states instead of a continuum. Assuming that there's a bias towards one direction you could still have a mostly dead somewhat alive cow or a mostly alive somewhat dead cow. Or you could wire the input through multiple potential melons so that the bias is canceled out.

Comment: That part of the code is messy.  I can't figure it out.  Should I post the code anyway?

Comment: So you ban the minecraft-enderman tag, but create the melon-mechanics tag? Care to explain yourself before I cry mod abuse?  :P

Comment: @John - posting questions after midnight. >.< Meant to be "Game-Mechanics", let me go fix that now.

Comment: @John - also, you may as well (post the code). I *am* a computer scientist, so I have at least as much chance at understanding it as you.

Comment: @RavenDreamer What texture pack are you using? It looks like a cleaner version of Piehole.

Comment: @soulBit it is Disco's OCD pack, that I have further modified for my own use. [Link](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/582711-16x181-ocd-pack-by-disco/)

Comment: Actually, that link looks dead at the moment. Here's a link to my custom (though outdated) Terrain.png instead. [Click](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2oVmm.png)

Comment: I vote for the melon-mechanics tag to be reinstated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I found the code that chooses where the melon grows.  (All comments added by me.)

```
int i1 = random.nextInt(4);
int j1 = i;  // Assuming j1 and k1 are the horizontal axes...
int k1 = k;
if(i1 == 0)  // North
{
    j1--;
}
if(i1 == 1) // South
{
    j1++;
}
if(i1 == 2) // East
{
    k1--;
}
if(i1 == 3) // West
{
    k1++; // or somthing like that, anyway.
}
if(world.getBlockId(j1, j, k1) == 0 && world.getBlockId(j1, j - 1, k1) == Block.tilledField.blockID)  // Make sure the targeted block is empty and below it is farmland...
{
    world.setBlockWithNotify(j1, j, k1, field_35297_a.blockID); // Place a melon.
}
```

It appears to depend on how random `random.nextInt(4)` is.

Comment: Excellent sleuthing! This looks like it *is* random then. Possibly also, you're more likely to grow a melon when you have 4 tilled blocks surrounding it?

Comment: Damn. Now I really want to pour through the rest of the Minecraft code.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer, what makes you so sure it really *is* random? [4, 4, 4, 4, 4 ...](http://xkcd.com/221/) would be a perfectly valid sequence.

Comment: @Cyclops - that's a problem with *any* program using java's rand library, though.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Glad I could help.  :)  The code appears to select a location, *then* check if it's tilled, only spawning if it is.  So you *are* more likely to grow a melon if all 4 surrounding tiles are farmland.

Comment: @John yeah, that's how I read it too.

Comment: One last question - any idea where I can find a decompiled version of Minecraft I can futz around with?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I use the [Minecraft Coder Pack](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Minecraft_Coder_Pack), but it's not yet compatible with anything newer than 1.8.1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738629/math-random-versus-random-nextintint Looks pretty fair to me!