# How can I pulse one of several wires in Minecraft randomly?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

My question is a bit familiar to [How can I randomly power one of several wires in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18616/how-can-i-randomly-power-one-of-several-wires-in-minecraft), but slightly different.

Let's say I have 5 wires (or more), wire A, B, C, D and E. Now, I want to randomly pulse one of them with the hit of a button. However, there should be a greater chance to pulse wire A and B, then the chance to pulse C and D. Also, the chance to pulse E should be smaller then A, B, C and D.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is *pretty* messy, but I think it can be done with some dropper randomizers. I'll mess with it a bit.

Comment: Would this help? [(Might be related to this question.)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18616/how-can-i-randomly-power-one-of-several-wires-in-minecraft)

Comment: Er @Sebie - He already quoted that question. Anyways, what you could do is follow the instructions outlined in that question THEN make a gate that when powered, it pulses an output and then cuts the output until the input is turned off (and back on again, like the way a button works, except reversed).

Answer (score 1):

Have a pulse going around in a loop.
Along one side, take the first repeater and set it to the longest time delay (for heightened probability), followed by 1 redstone, then the rest of the loop.

Should look like this:

Key:

I = Long setting
W = Redstone wire

Current is anticlockwise

```
wwwww
w   w
w   w
w   w
w   WWWWW
w   I
wwwww
```

Here the line of W's is line A.

Repeat with B

Next, repeat with C and D, but with shorter delays. (Probability)

Leave E without an extra delay.

Next, make an AND gate on each line. One input will be the button, the other will be the line. The output of those are the lines A, B, C, D and E.

Please comment if you don't understand and I will amend as appropriate.

Comment: Won't this just generate a sequence rather than a random (or psedorandom) triggers on the 5 wires

Comment: @RichardTingle It'll create a sort of roulette wheel effect, except without any visual feedback on where the wheel is. It's not ideal as far as randomness goes, but it's pretty effectively pseudorandom. The AND gates make it so an output is selected only when the button is pressed.