# Randomly select one of 3 hubs with command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This question is similar to [How can I randomly power one of several wires in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18616/how-can-i-randomly-power-one-of-several-wires-in-minecraft), but uses command blocks and only 3 outputs.

I'm making a Minecraft server and it has three different hubs that one can spawn in when they join the server. Each hub is identical.
When a player joins a the server, they spawn in a 1x2x1 box. This box has a pressure plate on the bottom. When the pressure plate is triggered, I want to be able to randomly select one of three hubs to teleport to. Is it possible to do this through command blocks? Or will I need to make a redstone device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summon an armor stands at the spawn point of each of the hubs like this:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1,Marker:1,NoGravity:1,Tags:["hub"]}
```

Then just put this command into the command block under the pressure plate:

```
tp @p @r[type=armor_stand,tag=hub]
```

This teleports the player to a random one of these invisible armor stands.

Comment: Wow, a brillant loophole. +1 for thinking outside of the box.

Comment: Actually, this is **the** standard way to do that.

Comment: Oh. Still. A good solution.

Comment: Yep, the best. That's why people use it. :D

Comment: Oh, wait, now that I've built it, my command block can't find the armor stands.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong with the tags list. Let me check, I haven't tried it until now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68198/discussion-between-pagie-and-fabian).

Comment: No, it's fixed now. "Tags" has to be capitalised. And @r only selects players by default.

Comment: So how do I make it select entities?

Comment: I already edited it, it now includes `type=armor_stand`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 3 armorstands with common tag (e.g "hub"), and place each of them to certain hub.

```
/scoreboard players tag @p[tag=!player,x=*,y=*,z=*,dx=0] add player
/execute @r[tag=hub,c=1] ~ ~ ~ /teleport @a[tag=player,c=1]
/scoreboard players tag @p[tag=player] remove player
```

* - coordinates of your box

Comment: This doesn't work. The first command selects no entity at all. The second command would only select **players** with that tag and the second half of the command doesn't work because of a bug.