# How to simulate polyhedral dice in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

A dispenser can simulate dice of up to nine sides by random choice, and there are redstone circuits for simulating six-sided dice. But how do you simulate, say, ten-sided, twelve-sided or twenty-sided dice in Minecraft?

Comment: Hehe, playing Dungeons & Dragons via Minecraft?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a counter that resets after **n** ticks, where **n** is the number of sides on your dice. You can see an overview of creating a counter on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter). All you need to do is add extra logic so that when the output matches **n**, it resets the counter to 0.

Hook up your counter to a fast clock with a switch to stop the clock to simulate rolling the dice. The number rolled will be displayed in binary.

Comment: You could use pigs jumping on plates for some actual randomness, rather than timing.