# How do you activate different redstone currents each time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

For a map I'm making, there's a "Palm Reader", represented by a villager. When you throw a diamond into a nearby hopper, it gives you a fortune. Is there a way to activate different `/say` command blocks each time, so its not just the same fortune over and over again?

I've done some research, and there doesn't seem to be anything on the topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [In Minecraft how do I randomise the output in a redstone circuit?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18133/in-minecraft-how-do-i-randomise-the-output-in-a-redstone-circuit) or [How can I make a random number generator with command blocks in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/229610/185203)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a loop which blocks all but one comparator at a time.

(I didn't have any command blocks, but you'll get the point)

(Scroll down for design (Paint markings))

[image: Screenshot]

In the circuit in the picture above you can see a loop with repeaters. Using the redstone all of the comparators but one are switched off, only allowing a current trough the one that is one.

When the user drops an item into the dispenser (use an item sorter to make sure it is a diamond), it will activate the command block which happens to be currenly accessible though the comparator.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: that looks really complicated o-o

Comment: @xXPikminXx It usually always does to begin with :) but if you follow it you'll be able to get a hang of it while you're building.

Comment: Nice job, obviously a lot of effort put into this answer. +1

Comment: it's just the way I think, It took me less than half a second to think out the design. installing minecraft and java afterwards took the most effort for me.

thanks!