# Having a 50-50 chance apply to commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm creating a game and I need a fill command to have a 50-50 chance of opening one of two gates (Ex. This will be activated when a button is pressed to start game).  The obvious choice would to use the @r selector, but I don't know how to apply this to a command block command.

I'm running 1.10.2 and this is only a two player game. (For me and a friend)

Comment: Maybe you find something useful [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229610/how-can-i-make-a-random-number-generator-with-command-blocks-in-minecraft). [This one](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/File:Random_selector_1.8_updated.png) doesn't even need a command block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this is using a random feature of the game, eg. Dispensers, animal movement, explosions, mob spawning and more. The easiest you can do is:

1. Fill a dispenser with 2 items - one stackable, one not - a helmet and a dirt block for example.
2. Put a Weighted Pressure Plate where the Dispenser shoots.
3. When you power the dispenser, it shoots one of the 2 items. The Pressure Plate will give stronger signal (goes farther) if a helmet (equivalent to a full stack) falls on it then if 1/64th of a stack of dirt falls on it.
4. Execute a command only if the signal reaches a certain strength.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback,  I hope to find a system that is constant and a bit more reliable though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "random" number generator by **periodically** changing the value of a objctive on a fast redstone clock:

(First create the objetcive by `/scoreboard objectives add FiftyFifty dummy`)

```
 /scoreboard objectives set @a FiftyFifty 0

 /scoreboard objectives set @a FiftyFifty 1
```

So the FiftyFifty objective is 50% of the time equal to 1. To trigger your command, you need to constantly run this command (in a repeat command block):

```
/testfor @a[score_FiftyFifty_min=1]
```

And if this command returns true, ecexute your command (in a Chain command block)