# Could I make a command block teleport the player to any of (for example) 5 given coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Hypixel, you are teleported to a random map when you play a game. How could I recreate this in my world?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a random number generator with command blocks in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229610/how-can-i-make-a-random-number-generator-with-command-blocks-in-minecraft)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to have entities at each point and teleport the player to a random entity with `@r`. Only works in loaded chunks though.

By default `@r` only selects players, so you have to specify a type. For armor stands for example it's `@r[type=armor_stand]`.

Comment: @r is random player and will not work in singleplayer

Comment: @r[type=pig] will specify a random pig

Comment: i did not know that

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately there is no way to randomize commands using JUST command blocks, so redstone is your only option.

The dropper randomizer works great, just have a dropper with a piece of dirt and a sword feed into a hopper, have a comparator detect what's in the hopper (1 length of redstone for dirt, 3 for the sword.) and have the 3 length cancel the first command and activate the second.

It sounds complex, but there are plenty of tutorials on YouTube under "dropper randomizer" that can help you.