# How do I teleport a player to a random position?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need a random number from -100 to 100 for a command block
/tp @p (random number 1) 200 (random number 2)

Comment: Within the game? It's not clear from your post.

Comment: I'm trying to get a to command in a command block that goes /tp @p (random) 200 (random). The 2 random numbers need to be different. I've edited the post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a random number generator with command blocks in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229610/how-can-i-make-a-random-number-generator-with-command-blocks-in-minecraft)

Comment: Strongly disagree with this proposed duplication. This is a classic example of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). This question is not really asking how to generate a number, it is asking how to teleport a player to a random location within specified parameters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to directly generate a random number using commands, and there definitely isn't any way to then plug that random number into another command block.

However, the [`spreadplayers`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/spreadplayers) command will do what you're after here. `spreadplayers` is designed to place groups of, or individual players, in random spots around the map.

The syntax is as follows for Java Edition: `/spreadplayers <x> <z> <spreadDistance> <maxRange> <respectTeams> <player>`. `<x> <z>` specifies the center of the map, `<spreadDistance>` specifies the minimum distance between the targets, `<maxRange>` specifies the maximum horizontal distance to place players from the center, `<respectTeams>` specifies whether or not teams should be kept together, and `<player>` specifies your targets.

In the particular case of sending a single `@p` to some location between x,z (-100,-100) and (100,100), the command would look like so:

```
/spreadplayers 0 0 0 100 false @p
```

Comment: I suspect what you're really after is spreading a bunch of players around the map to random spots, which can be accomplished by subbing in an `@a` to the final command here.

Comment: If this works in 1.12 (which I didn't specify in the question, sorry) I'll mark this as correct

Comment: @RobertLucas It should, it was added in 1.6.1 and I don't see anything to suggest that it has been changed since then for Java Edition, so it should work in 1.12.

Comment: It's for 1 person