# Minecraft Portal/Teleporting between 2 Overworlds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would prefer if my players can walk in the Custom Portal i made with water and they get teleported to another place in another Overworld (World). It would still be okay with presure plate. I just don't know how to make that. Can anyone Help me with this ? Also my server is 1.16.4.

Comment: This might help you out. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359781/how-do-i-teleport-a-player-to-a-random-position

Comment: Have you created another dimension yet? Or you don't know how?

Answer (score -1):

If you will build them in vanilla it doesn´t work to teleport to another dimension, but you can teleport someone very far away if this player stands in end gateway in the overworld. The command is `/execute as @a in minecraft:overworld at @s if block ~ ~ ~ minecraft:end_gateway run tp @s x y z`.