# Minecraft execute random command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Update: To be clear, I've got 3 commands, and I want 1 of the 3 to execute, effectively on loop.

I've got a couple command blocks, each with some commands, and I want them to execute at random intervals.

My strategy so far is to use chickens that wonder in a pen stepping on pressure plates, but they don't move often enough and I'd rather not just resort to duplicting commands:

[image: Image of chickens in a pen, stepping on pressure plates to activate commands]

I've tried a lot of ideas with the chickens, (speed effects, spawning an entity holding seeds), but I think I'll need something better.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want specifically? One command randomly selected from a list, executed at randomised intervals?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a random number generator with command blocks in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229610/how-can-i-make-a-random-number-generator-with-command-blocks-in-minecraft)

Comment: I've got 3 commands, and I want 1 of the 3 to execute, but not be in a consistent order

Answer (score 2):

I've found a potential solution that uses a chicken and an ocelot. Summon a chicken with Speed II and Instant Health II and a regular ocelot - the ocelot will chase the chicken around continuously, triggering pressure plates, and the chicken will never die.

[image]

Command to spawn a chicken (1.15): `/summon chicken ~ ~1 ~ {PersistenceRequired:1,CustomName:"\"Always running 2\"",ActiveEffects:[{Id:1,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999},{Id:6,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999}]}`