# Is it possible to have random numbers in commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So we already know I have an anarchy world and I want to "troll" some players with a command block with a simple goal.

**"One the button is pressed, you will be teleported in a random area, and maybe you can make your base there."**

So unlike [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229610/how-can-i-make-a-random-number-generator-with-command-blocks-in-minecraft), I want to set up a `/tp` on the command that kinda goes like this:

```
/tp @p [rand=100000,-100000] 255 [rand=100000,-100000] true
```

Now I'm thinking of setting the coordinates to a random `int` without adding a mod or some additional code (because I don't know how to add it in or make one even though I'm a programmer).

Is it possible to set random numbers in a teleportation command in Bedrock Edition?

Comment: Please don't assert that what you are asking for is possible. Minecraft has never had good support for randomness, and Bedrock Edition has a very restricted command format. It's hard enough to accomplish your task in Java Edition, let alone in Bedrock. So if you aren't 100% sure that what you're asking for is possible, please fall back to asking *"is it possible"* rather than *"how to do it"*.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I mean... does that phrasing really make that much of a difference?

Comment: Just use the `/spreadplayers` command, it would be more customizable anyway

Comment: @Penguin Yes. The original phrasing basically brings up the tone that they won't accept a "that's impossible" answer. When you ask "is it possible," it tells others that you're open to the fact that what you're asking for may not be possible.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 It really isn't as big of a deal as you are making it. Just edit the post, write what you are editing in the log, and go about your day.

Comment: @Penguin Make that an answer? It makes sense, and I don't think we will find any possible way for a /tp command to do what he wants.

Comment: @Potterton Look, I did edit the post, if you would have looked at the revision history before writing your comment. I only commented so that they wouldn't make the same mistake in the future. Sure, they could just look at the edit history, but if they don't, my comment is insurance.

Comment: @Potterton I don't really think of these issues as big deals. In fact, that issue that I corrected is not that big at all! The only reason it becomes a big deal in my eyes is because it becomes a big deal in others' eyes. Someone out there will make it a big deal, so I will edit it so that it satisfies them.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 apparently no matter what you do no one will be happy xD

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 & @ Penguin No worries for you both. I was just trying to let some fresh air in. I know what you mean. Happy Arqading!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `/spreadplayers` command:

`spreadplayers <x: value> <z: value> <spreadDistance: float> <maxRange: float> <victim: target>`

X and Z is the center of the range in XZ-plane you wish to start the spread. Spread distance is irrelevant if only randomly placing a single player (it's the minimum distance a player must be placed away from other players) and can be 0. Max range is the maximum distance away from the XZ center the player is to be randomly placed. `victim` is any selector and in bedrock can apply to any entity, not just players.

As for general randomness for selectors, there isn't a direct syntax to apply random numbers, but you can use the random player selector (@r) anywhere you need an entity selector so long as you specify 'type' with the selector. For example `/kill @r[type=zombie]` kills a random zombie.

Comment: Nice command. Looks like my game crashed, but I enjoyed it. I guess it helps, just not the way I expected.