# How to generate a random number in 1.18.1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have fiddled around with a data pack which needs a random number. To get that, I have tried using emeraldfyr3's random function, which is quite outdated by now, but I have updated it to the best of my knowledge. However, when running the command, instead of a random number, it just always returns the current math_output value + 50. Any ideas on where the issue lies, how I could fix it and/or how I could get a random number perhaps with other, better methods?

```
#Change (lower, upper) to (lower, range)
scoreboard players set @s math_input1 50
scoreboard players set @s math_input2 10070
scoreboard players operation @s math_input2 -= @s math_input1
scoreboard players add @s math_input2 1
```

```
#Summon two entities to work with
summon minecraft:area_effect_cloud ~ ~ ~ {Duration:1,CustomName:'{"text":"math_random_kcjbc"}'}
summon minecraft:area_effect_cloud ~ ~ ~ {Duration:1,CustomName:'{"text":"math_random_kcjbc"}'}
```

```
#Generate a 31-bit random number by randomizing each bit
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 1
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 2
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 4
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 8
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 16
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 32
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 64
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 128
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 256
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 512
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 1024
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 2048
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 4096
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 8192
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 16384
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 32768
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 65536
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 131072
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 262144
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 524288
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 1048576
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 2097152
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 4194304
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 8388608
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 16777216
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 33554432
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 67108864
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 134217728
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 268435456
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 536870912
scoreboard players add @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1,sort=random] math_input1 1073741824
```

```
#Transfer random number and limit to given range
scoreboard players operation @s math_output = @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=0,limit=1] math_input1
scoreboard players operation @s math_output %= @s math_input2
scoreboard players operation @s math_output += @s math_input1
```

```
scoreboard players operation @s math_input2 += @s math_input1
scoreboard players remove @s math_input2 1
```

```
function srm_func:mechanics/main
```

```
kill @e[type=minecraft:area_effect_cloud,name=math_random_kcjbc,distance=..1]
```

Comment: Not going to close as duplicate, but see [What sources of randomness can be made with commands in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/229610/185203)

Comment: @pppery I was on that link before, but didn't go through all answers, as all the ones at the top didn't seem to good to me, but at the bottom there is the UUID method and I love it. I don't care if it's only the second best or whatever, it's awesome and really compact. So if anyone is looking for an answer to this, I can really recommend the UUID one. And thanks again to you pppery

Comment: Formally casting a close vote as duplicate since the duplicate did, in the end, solve the original asker's problem.