# Randomly Selecting Items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I am working on a command block based card game in Minecraft. Players play with preconstructed decks of, say, 30 cards. Originally, I loaded the preconstructed decks into a dropper and randomly dispensed items as players drew cards. However, this creates an issue as if a player has 4 copies of one card left in their deck and 1 copy of another, they are equally as likely to draw either of them (as the items are stacked in the dropper). I need each card to have a chance of being drawn proportionate to the number of copies left. For example, if you have 4 copies of "Divination" and 2 copies of "Giant Squid" in your deck, the next time you draw a card, it has a 2/3 chance of being Divination and 1/3 chance of being Giant Squid.

I'm honestly not sure what direction to go in to randomize the items. Any suggestions are open, including ones that would allow for more cards in a deck (30 was chosen because it's less than the 36 you can fit in a dropper where the maximum number of a given card is 4).

So far I have only tried to drop all of the cards out of a dropper. I then teleport a random one to the player who is drawing a card. The issue here is that the items will, of course, stack. If there is a way to prevent dropped item stacking (note the cards all have specific names and lore) altogether, that would be a perfect solution.

Of course, there may just not be a simple solution without building a large-scale randomizer, which is something I'd like to avoid if possible.

Thank you in advance :)

EDIT: The cards are blocks, and need to remain as them. Nonstackables are not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

While you can make same-ish items unstackable by giving them some form of different nbt tag (e.g. `/give @p gold_block{unique:1}` won't stack with one that has the `{unique:2}` tag), that would certainly cause issues with your dropper method in general (as a dropper only has 9 slots). The custom data is also lost when the block is placed down and picked up again.

---

See pretty much all the answers on this question regarding random numbers: [What sources of randomness can be made with commands in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229610/what-sources-of-randomness-can-be-made-with-commands-in-minecraft)
I don't think you can call most of these "large scale", which is why I'm linking them for you.

---

But in your case if all you need is one of X random items to be given to a player, while also eliminating items that have been given once, I'd recommend doing it like this:

1. summon all the items in some loaded but not accessible location. Set their `Age` to -32768 to make sure they never despawn (use https://mcstacker.net to create the correct commands).
   `/summon item ~ ~ ~ {Age:-32768,Item:{id:"minecraft:gold_block",Count:1b,tag:{unique:1}}}`
2. Use `@e[type=item,sort=random,limit=1]` to select one at random and teleport it to the current player.

This way every card has the same chance of being picked because they all are individual entities. This way you also have a lot more freedom when it comes to designing the game with how many cards you want to add.

Comment: Hey thanks a ton! That solution works perfectly. Did not know you could summon items and prevent them from stacking that way.

Comment: @SammySammyson remember to accept the answer that solved your problem by clicking on the little checkmark underneath the vote buttons. :)