# How can I generate an output from one in 6 possibilities with vanilla redstone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to be able to hit a button, and 5 out of 6 times have nothing happen, but on the 1 out of 6 time, I want it to give a pulse output. This is to make a Russian roulette game, I'd like the input to be a button because I want to charge tokens to play it on a server with friends.

If you press the button, there's a 1/6 chance that a dispenser will fire out a single tent, and a 5/6 chance that nothing happens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Minecraft how do I randomise the output in a redstone circuit?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18133/in-minecraft-how-do-i-randomise-the-output-in-a-redstone-circuit)

Comment: Not exactly, I might just not be understanding but I don't see how it helps..

Comment: Since you're already using a dispenser, you can just use one stack of fire balls and five stacks of snow balls. No other circuit needed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This method makes use of the fact that non stackable items emit a higher comparator signal than stackables.
Take 5 dirt blocks(any 64 stack item) and a sword(any unstackable).
Put these 6 items in a single dropper and take another dropper, make these 2 face each other.
Every time the dropper fires, it will throw out a random item. We can take a comparator output from the second, and if there is line strength more than one, [insert deadly roulette trap here].
If u want it to be a one in six chance, give a signal to second dropper to reset it. If u want it to fire once every six times, make the second dropper output to a locked hopper instead, and using a comparator, detect when 1st dropper is empty and unlock the hopper to let the items in(don't directly unlock hopper from 1st observer comparator output,use a pulse extender to let all six items back).